# runtime error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/session.lua:183: loop or previous error loading module 'resty.session.ciphers.aes'

Tags: nginx, lua, keycloak, lua-resty-openidc

This is the error i am getting

```
lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/session.lua:183: loop or previous error loading module 'resty.session.ciphers.aes'
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/session.lua:183: in function 'new'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/session.lua:222: in function 'open'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/session.lua:286: in function 'start'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/openidc.lua:1361: in function 'authenticate'
        access_by_lua(keycloak.conf:25):15: in function <access_by_lua(keycloak.conf:25):1>
```

and here my keycloak.conf nging file

```
 server {
       listen     80 default_server;
       server_name  www.keycloak.com;
       root     /opt/nginx/html;
       access_by_lua '
         local opts = {
           redirect_uri_path = "/redirect_uri",
           accept_none_alg = true,
           discovery = "http://www.keyclock.com:8080/auth/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration",
           client_id = "nginx",
           client_secret = "84a5616b-9cee-4feeecc-836f-8856c958ef54",
           redirect_uri_scheme = "http",
           logout_path = "/logout",
           redirect_after_logout_uri = "http://www.keycloak.com:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http://www.keyclock.com/",
           redirect_after_logout_with_id_token_hint = false,
           session_contents = {id_token=true}
         }
         -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
         local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
         if err then
           ngx.status = 403
           ngx.say(err)
           ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
         end
      ';
      # I disabled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
      expires           0;
      add_header        Cache-Control private;
      location / {
      }
      # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
      #
      error_page 404 /404.html;
          location = /40x.html {
      }
      # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
      #
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
      }
  }
```

> Installed LUA packages are
>    lua-cjson
>    luaffi
>    lua-resty-http
>    lua-resty-jwt
>    lua-resty-openidc
>    lua-resty-session

I hope i installed required packages of lua may be the issue is at nginx config file at line 25 **local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)**